# Most basic react-native-maps not working (Expo)

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

I am trying to get the most basic map to show in my react native app but it just shows a blank screen.
Here is my code...

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    Button
} from 'react-native';

//Import map
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';


class TodaysJobs extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MapView
                initialRegion={{
                  latitude: 37.78825,
                  longitude: -122.4324,
                  latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                  longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default TodaysJobs;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    logo: {
        width: '60%',
        resizeMode: 'contain'
    },
    navButton: {
        width: '60%',
        marginTop: 20,
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

If I try `import { MapView } from 'react-native-maps';` instead I get this error...

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

My API for app.json looks like this:

```
"android": {
        "config": {
            "googleMaps": {
                "apiKey": "MYAPIKEYkmdsa;jfpjP(pJPOEFKm;"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew I was dumb but damn. Sorry my styles where not set up....

```
mapStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
},
```